# How to cancel the trash action inside wp_trash_post

Tags: hooks, trash

I need to restrict the button **"EMPTY TRASH"** and make it delete only the posts only if the logged in user is the creator.

I tried to use the `wp_trash_post` and i need to decide in the function if i need to continue to trash or not.

How do i tell WordPress NOT to empty the trash from specific posts?

Comment: Then how you will be able to trash the post ? Why don't you give author access to your users ?

Comment: Every user must be able to manage its own posts from specific post types. So i have managed to bullet proof all other operations (create,edit,view)....I am still having problem for only this action...to make it clearer, for example me pre_get_posts gets posts only if the author is the logged in user....So basically i need a "EMPTY MY OWN POSTS ONLY"....

Comment: I would also like an answer to this question. When using post_types for syncing data via an API it would be nice to not delete/trash the post, but just set a property 'deleted' or 'published=false' so I can send removed posts in the stream of recently changed items.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to utilize the [`pre_delete_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_delete_post/) filter to short-circuit the deleting of posts.

```
add_filter( 'pre_delete_post', 'wpse_224246_pre_delete_post', 10, 3 );
function wpse_224246_pre_delete_post( $delete, $post, $force_delete ) {
  //* Escape early if post isn't already trashed
  if( 'trash' !== $post->post_status ) {
    return $delete;
  }
  //* Go ahead with deleting the post if the current user is the post author 
  if( get_current_user_id() === $post->post_author ) {
    return $delete;
  }
  //* Returning any other value besides null will short circuit the deletion
  return true;
}
```